I'm trying to filter an array to print read book using express but it can not be read or empty result
I have a booklist and try to print out those already read in 'title by author' form
const bookList = [
    {title: "Harry Potter", author: "J.K. Rowling", alreadyRead: true},
    {title: "Never Eat Alone", author: "Keith Ferrazzi", alreadyRead: false},
    {title: "INSPIRED", author: "Marty Cagan", alreadyRead: false},
    {title: "Zero to One", author: "Peter Thiel", alreadyRead: true}
]

at first I use this for loop method by passing the booklist and status to call the function printBookList(bookList, true) but it end up printing all the elements in the list
function printBookList(bookList, completedReadingBook){
    for(i=0;i<bookList.length;i++){
        if (bookList[i].alreadyRead == completedReadingBook) {
            console.log(bookList[i].title + ' by ' + bookList[i].author);
        }
    }  
}

then I also try with filter() method as below but it end up showing empty
for(i=0; i<bookList.length;i++){
    let filtered = bookList.filter((readbook)=>readbook.alreadyRead==completedReadingBook)
    return filtered;
    }
    console.log(bookList[filtered].title + ' by ' + bookList[filtered].author);

I'm quite new to this js, will be much appreciate if someone could explain this to me, thx a lot!

you don't need to run booklist.filter in a for loop ... and the return means the console.log can never happen ... though, bookList[filtered] is not meaningful ... remove the for(i ... etc and you'll find filtered is an array of bookList that matches the filter condition

note: your first attempt could not possibly (and DOES NOT when your code is executed) output the whole bookList

As Jaromanda X pointed out:

your first naive for-loop function should work (and does work when I copy-paste-run it) fine;
Array.filter() is a method called upon the whole array;
not sure if your second piece of code is inside a function or not, but if it is, indeed the last line (the console.log()) will never be executed because it is after the return statement; if it is not, then the return statement shouldn't be there;
filtered is an array, not an index, so bookList[filtered] is incorrect semantics.

You can read the documentation on Array.filter() here, and your second piece of code ought to look something like this:
function printBooklist(bookList, completedReadingBook) {
  const filtered = bookList.filter((readbook)=>readbook.alreadyRead==completedReadingBook);
  for(i=0; i<bookList.length;i++){
    console.log(filtered[i].title + ' by ' + filtered[i].author);
  }
}

You can also use built-in JS methods like Object.groupBy and forEach:


function printReadBooks() {
  const bookList = [
    {title: "Harry Potter", author: "J.K. Rowling", alreadyRead: true},
    {title: "Never Eat Alone", author: "Keith Ferrazzi", alreadyRead: false},
    {title: "INSPIRED", author: "Marty Cagan", alreadyRead: false},
    {title: "Zero to One", author: "Peter Thiel", alreadyRead: true}
  ];
  // Object.groupBy returns an object grouped by the alreadyRead property.
  const readBooks = Object.groupBy(bookList, ({alreadyRead}) => alreadyRead).true;
 
  console.log("Already read books:");
  // forEach iterates through every list item in readBooks.
  readBooks.forEach(({title, author}) => console.log(` - ${title}, by ${author};\n`));
 
  /* The following line will only work in some environments:
  readBooks.forEach(({title, author}) =>
                    console.log(` - %c${title}%c, by ${author};\n`,
                                "font-style: italic", "font-style: normal")); */
}

printReadBooks();



